# Service routing rest json services

Tags: wcf, json

WCF: whats is the best binding one for rest json service behind the routing service? can i use net.tcp?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That's easy: in WCF world, **REST = `webHttpBinding`** - any other binding is SOAP.